# Is there findFirst with position in predicate in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to find first element in a list which fits predicate. But I need to check with it position in predicate.

```
    list.findXXX { index, item ->
        index > 19 && item.active
    }
```

Is there such a function?

Comment: If your condition is simply `index > 19`, you can just use a sublist and use `firstOrNull` on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function yet, but you can easily write one yourself. It is not a lot of effort at all.

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.findIndexed(predicate: (Int, T) -> Boolean): T? {
    forEachIndexed { i, e -> if (predicate(i, e)) return e }
    return null
}
```

Alternatively, in general you can use a `filterIndexed` to first filter out the indexes that you want to exclude:

```
list
//  .asSequence() // if you want to be lazy
    .filterIndexed { i, _ -> i > 19 }
    .find { item -> item.active }
```

In fact, you could just put the entire condition in `filterIndexed` and use `firstOrNull` afterwards. It just may not read as nicely as  `find`.

Of course in this specific case you can also just `drop` the first 20.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with such function, but I think this would work well for your example

```
list.drop(20).first{item -> item.isActive}
```

Comment: The example condition I've provided is not good as I don't really need to drop elements, but Thank you! That would defenetely work in some cases

Comment: @RusArtM keep in mind that `drop()` doesn't actually modify the list. It doesn't actually drop things from the list. It returns a new list

Answer (score 1):

You can make your custom extension function to achieve what you want

```
fun <T> List<T>.firstCustomOrNull(
    predicate: (index: Int, element: T) -> Boolean
): T? {
    forEachIndexed { index, element ->
        if (predicate(index, element)) return element
    }

    return null
}
```

now you can use that function the same way as `.firstOrNull` and you have access to the element and the index so you can use it in any custom way that you want:

```
list.firstCustomOrNull { index, element ->
    element.active && index > 19
}
```

This solution will work for any case and you can customize it more, but if you want to keep it simple you can just drop the first 20 element.